# Bash script within Docker container unexpected "permission denied"

Tags: bash, docker

I am using the amazonlinux image to test a server setup script without spending time and money on real EC2 instances. However, I cannot get the script to execute within the container.

I am running with the following command: `docker run -v script.sh:/tmp/script.sh -w /tmp amazonlinux ./script.sh

Which fails with `"Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./script.sh\": permission denied": unknown.`

1. The script permissions are `-rwxrwxrwx` on the host.
2. Permissions inside the container are `drwxr-xr-x`.
3. The user in the container is `root`.

Comment: Is /home/root/amazonlinux a valid path/directory?

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras /home/root is the working directory, amazonlinux is the image name.

Comment: Inside the container `/home/root/script.sh/` is a directory (that's the leading "d" in your point 2).  That happens if the path on the host doesn't exist, among other things.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku /home/root exists?

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras No, but i changed the path to one which does with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: 
`docker run -v ${PWD}/script.sh:/home/root/script.sh -w /home/root amazonlinux ./script.sh`

Comment: This helped, but please explain why it matters.

Comment: I'm always using the full path of the source volume that been mounted, use `docker inspect` command to see the behavior in your case.

Comment: if you do not specify the full path docker assume that this is a name of the volume